# Inject scoped config into DataProvider in Magento 2.4

Tags: admin, magento2.4, grid, data-provider

I am trying to make a tabular/grid view in the Admin area for some data that comes from an external API. For that I implemented a data provider. In here I need to create an instance for the external API client with the config stored in the store settings.

However, I am not sure how to inject or retrieve these settings in the data provider:

```
class ListingDataProvider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider
{
...
 public function __construct(
         $name,
         $primaryFieldName,
         $requestFieldName,
         ReportingInterface $reporting,
         SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
         RequestInterface $request,
         FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
         array $meta = [],
         array $data = [],
          ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig <---- Is this possible?
     ) {
         $this->request = $request;
         $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
         $this->name = $name;
         $this->primaryFieldName = $primaryFieldName;
         $this->requestFieldName = $requestFieldName;
         $this->reporting = $reporting;
         $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
         $this->meta = $meta;
         $this->data = $data;
         $this->prepareUpdateUrl();
}
...
}
```

This is my (probably wrong) di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <type name="Some\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Administration\ListingDataProvider">
   <plugin name="some_module_attributes" type="Some\Module\Plugin\AddAttributesToUiDataProvider"/>
 </type>
 <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
  <arguments>
   <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="some_module__administration_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">SomeModuleAdministrationCollection</item>
   </argument>
  </arguments>
 </type>
  // Not quite sure how should this be replaced
 <virtualType name="SomeModuleAdministrationCollection" type="Some\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Administration\Listing\Collection">
   <arguments>
     <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">catalog_category_entity</argument>
     <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Some\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Administration</argument>
   </arguments>
 </virtualType>
</config>
```

I am sure the  above is wrong, as i do not have a mainTable.
But, is it possible to inject the config?
Or, if I inject the config paths, how would I retrieve them in the provider class itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can inject ScopeConfig into DataProvider class but as of Magento 2.4.4 (use PHP 8.1) require parameters have to declare before the optional parameters.

Assume your DataProvider has the code:

```
class ListingDataProvider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider
{
    ...
    public function __construct(
         $name,
         $primaryFieldName,
         $requestFieldName,
         ReportingInterface $reporting,
         SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
         RequestInterface $request,
         FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
         array $meta = [],
         array $data = []
    ) {
         $this->request = $request;
         $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
         $this->name = $name;
         $this->primaryFieldName = $primaryFieldName;
         $this->requestFieldName = $requestFieldName;
         $this->reporting = $reporting;
         $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
         $this->meta = $meta;
         $this->data = $data;
         $this->prepareUpdateUrl();
    }
    ...
}
```

You should inject ScopeConfig like this:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class ListingDataProvider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider
{
    ...
    public function __construct(
         $name,
         $primaryFieldName,
         $requestFieldName,
         ReportingInterface $reporting,
         SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
         RequestInterface $request,
         FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
         ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
         array $meta = [],
         array $data = []
    ) {
         $this->request = $request;
         $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
         $this->name = $name;
         $this->primaryFieldName = $primaryFieldName;
         $this->requestFieldName = $requestFieldName;
         $this->reporting = $reporting;
         $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
         $this->meta = $meta;
         $this->data = $data;
         $this->prepareUpdateUrl();
         $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you can get store config by:

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('sectionId/groupId/fieldId', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

For creating a Grid using UI component without a database table, take look at this document: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/ui-components/components/listing-grid/#examples. And you can take a look at this post for reference too: [Magento 2 UI grid non db dataprovider and pagination issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209682/magento-2-ui-grid-non-db-dataprovider-and-pagination-issue)

Feel free to let me know if you still need help after that.